# Time signature of Goldberg Variation 8

Tags: time-signatures

I can only hear it as 1-and-ah 2-and-ah, which would (I thought) make it 6/8, but it’s labeled as 3/4.

Actually, if I’m counting in quarter notes, I can only hear 2/4 (1-and 2-and).

(I heard it initially on the 1955 Glenn Gould recording, but it’s the same here:

.)

New to this.

How can I get my brain to hear the 3/4 meter?

Comment: Yes; I am asking how to get my brain to hear the 3/4 meter. I have already tried offering it cookies. Now I am reaching out to see if there are other means of convincing it of which I am not yet aware, given my inexperience.

Comment: Instead of "1-and-ah", just count "1-2-3"?  Or are you feeling each 1/8 as the and-ah?  If so, look at the pattern for the right hand, the sets of 1/16ths.  You would want to try to hear each set of 4 as a single beat.  You could try turn the "1-and-ah, 2-and-ah" into "1-and, 2-and, 3-and" too.

Comment: Gotta say, most of it could easily be 6/8 to me too. It really depends how the second bar of each 'pair' is played. I challenge people to listen without knowing it's written in 3/4.

Comment: @Tim You make a good point - IMHO the challenge is for the *player* to play it in such a way that it's clear it's 3/4.

Comment: I wonder what actual difference it makes to any listener. 3/4 or 6/8, it's still a well crafted very listenable piece, and the 3/4 6/8 'debate' probably detracts from the piece itself. I very much doubt that most listeners will actually be thinking 'I wonder if it's..., but actually enjoying the moments it brings. Academia - eat your heart out..!

Comment: In terms of *performance,* especially on the original instrument (harpsichord not piano, with very limited dynamics) the solution is articulation and phrasing. I would play the first two 8th notes of the LH slurred together (with the second note shortened), and the next two 8ths detached. That will give a signal that there were two 8ths in the first beat, not three. Also, detach the first of the three 16 notes and slur the other two together, and separate them from the first note of the next bar.

Comment: This is a nice illustration of a general point about "hearing" rhythm (and other aspects of music as well) - you can only understand what you heard *retrospectively*. Four "identical" 8th notes are very ambiguous. The rest after the fourth one will make you pay more attention to it and tend to interpret (with hindsight, when the rest occurs!) as a beat. So if the performer doesn't want the listener to think that, the answer is *not* to play four "identical" notes.

Comment: Along alephzero's lines, if one is on an instrument in an acoustical environment where one can pull this off, one can slur together the first 2 16th notes in each beat in the *right* hand and detach everything else in the right hand..

Comment: I've heard a few recordings where the performer really plays it in 3/4.  I think most of them were on harpsichord.  Listen to a bunch of different recordings until you fine one or a few that sound like they're in three.  That will help you get the three into your ear.  Then again, it's possible that the ambiguity is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably **counting**. Out loud. Along with the music. If you can play it yourself, I suggest counting while playing.

Particularly the left hand part fits well with the meter. It hits four eighth notes (quavers) and then pauses on the third beat before "falling down" four 16th notes to hit the downbeat of the next measure.

I suggest counting "one ee & uh two ee & uh three ee & uh" while listening or playing and see if that helps you feel how the notes fit in with the beat.

Comment: I think the left hand may be the issue here for this listener.  They may be hearing the upbeat of beat 2 as the downbeat for beat 2 within 6/8.  Counting along will certainly be helpful either way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a lot of 6/8 in that 3/4.  Quite intentional I think.  The theme is in 3/4.  Bach gives us a 'varied' look at 3/4.   There's another one in the 18/16 against 3/4 of Var.26.

I don't think there's any particular virtue in emphasizing 'three in a bar'.  After sampling a few online performances, I haven't yet found a player who does.

Comment: How many of those performances were on a harpsichord?